# Binomial distribution using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, networkx, binomial-cdf

I have sampled some data from a network `G` with discrete values of node degrees in a network and calculated the distribution.

```
def degree_distribution(G):
    vk = dict(G.degree())
    vk = list(vk.values()) # we get only the degree values
    maxk = np.max(vk)
    mink = np.min(min)
    kvalues= np.arange(0,maxk+1) # possible values of k
    Pk = np.zeros(maxk+1) # P(k)
    for k in vk:
        Pk[k] = Pk[k] + 1
    Pk = Pk/sum(Pk) # the sum of the elements of P(k) must to be equal to one
    
    return kvalues,Pk
```

---

Calling it:

```
kvalues, Pk = degree_distribution(G)
dict_prob = dict(zip(kvalues,Pk))
```

I get:

```
{0: 0.0,
 1: 0.0,
 2: 0.0016146393972012918,
 3: 0.004843918191603875,
 4: 0.011840688912809472,
 5: 0.03336921420882669,
 6: 0.07319698600645856,
 7: 0.10764262648008611,
 8: 0.15177610333692143,
 9: 0.16361679224973089,
 10: 0.16254036598493002,
 11: 0.11679224973089343,
 12: 0.08880516684607104,
 13: 0.052206673842841764,
 14: 0.02099031216361679,
 15: 0.006996770721205597,
 16: 0.003767491926803014}
```

How do I test this sampled data for a binomial distribution, using `scipy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know how how good a fit is a binomial PMF to your empirical distribution, you can simply do:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats, optimize

data = {0: 0.0,
 1: 0.0,
 2: 0.0016146393972012918,
 3: 0.004843918191603875,
 4: 0.011840688912809472,
 5: 0.03336921420882669,
 6: 0.07319698600645856,
 7: 0.10764262648008611,
 8: 0.15177610333692143,
 9: 0.16361679224973089,
 10: 0.16254036598493002,
 11: 0.11679224973089343,
 12: 0.08880516684607104,
 13: 0.052206673842841764,
 14: 0.02099031216361679,
 15: 0.006996770721205597,
 16: 0.003767491926803014}

x = np.array(list(data.keys()))
y = np.array(list(data.values()))

def binom_fit(x, n, p):
    return stats.binom(n, p).pmf(x)
opt = optimize.curve_fit(binom_fit, x, y, [10, 0.5])
opt_n, opt_p = opt[0]

yhat = stats.binom(opt_n, opt_p).pmf(x)

R2 = 1 - np.sum((y - yhat)**2)/np.sum((y - y.mean())**2)

plt.plot(x, y, label="Empirical")
plt.plot(x, yhat, label="Binomial PMF")
plt.title(f"R^2 = {R2:0.4f}")
plt.legend()
```

Which gives:
[image: Binomial PMF fit]

Edit:
To test the hypothesis that the empirical frequencies follow the expected ones from a binomial distribution, you could use stats.chisquare:

```
>>> stats.chisquare(y*opt_n, yhat*(y.sum()/yhat.sum())*opt_n)
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=0.09436186207390668, pvalue=0.9999999999999994)
```

Note that the null hypothesis here is that the frequencies are the same, so a p-value > 0.05 would be evidence for the null.

Comment: beautiful. does stats object return me a p-valu3 so I can perfom a test hipothesis for the `binom` dist? If you could add me the test implementation, I'd gladly grant you you a bounty for it.

Comment: Unfortunately not directly. One option: you could use `stats.chisquare` test the hypothesis that your empirical frequencies follow the expected ones from a binomial distribution: `stats.chisquare(y*opt_n, yhat*(y.sum()/yhat.sum())*opt_n)`. Note that the null hypothesis here is that the frequencies are the same, so a p-value > 0.05 would be evidence for the null.

Comment: great, if you complement you answer with that extra snippet, making the null hypothesis clear, I'll grand you the bounty!

Comment: Sure, added the comment above to the answer.